# error:cannot convert 'std::complex<double>' to '__complex__ float' in initialization

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error posted in the title.  The C++ code I have will run in C++98 but not in any subsequent C++ releases like 11 or 14, etc., which I need to use.

Any thoughts?

```
    extern _Complex float gRESAMPLE_DSSS_PAGEDCOEFS_REVERSE_CONJ_TAPS17_STEP5000KHZ_BW20MHZ_FS20MHZ[];

_Complex float gRESAMPLE_DSSS_PAGEDCOEFS_REVERSE_CONJ_TAPS17_STEP5000KHZ_BW20MHZ_FS20MHZ[187] =
{
+1.91232115e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +2.05319226e-02-0.00000000e+00i, -2.72482540e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +4.17710021e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
-6.60308301e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +1.07876487e-01-0.00000000e+00i, -1.98891580e-01-0.00000000e+00i, +6.31532013e-01-0.00000000e+00i,
+6.31532013e-01-0.00000000e+00i, -1.98891580e-01-0.00000000e+00i, +1.07876487e-01-0.00000000e+00i, -6.60308301e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
+4.17710021e-02-0.00000000e+00i, -2.72482540e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +2.05319226e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +1.91232115e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
-2.01950068e-04-0.00000000e+00i, +1.57716405e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +2.58155894e-02-0.00000000e+00i, -3.05156335e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
+4.43429612e-02-0.00000000e+00i, -6.73551857e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +1.05998978e-01-0.00000000e+00i, -1.86539873e-01-0.00000000e+00i,
+5.19834042e-01-0.00000000e+00i, +7.33756542e-01-0.00000000e+00i, -1.96507320e-01-0.00000000e+00i, +1.01235323e-01-0.00000000e+00i,
-5.93557656e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +3.57483588e-02-0.00000000e+00i, -2.17679292e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +1.41898394e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
+2.25500409e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +4.04566905e-04-0.00000000e+00i, +1.26300994e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +2.98684780e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
-3.14745754e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +4.35172319e-02-0.00000000e+00i, -6.36360645e-02-0.00000000e+00i, +9.64822844e-02-0.00000000e+00i,
};
```

Where in reality the size of the complex matrix is actually 187 large....I just didnt paste it in for rooms sake.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_Complex float` is a C flavor of complex numbers, which shouldn't exist in C++. Your compiler allows it as an extension.

`1.23i` is a C++ `std::complex` literal.

`_Complex` and `std::complex` are not compatible with each other. You should use one or the other.

Replace `_Complex float` with `std::complex<float>` everywhere in your code, and change `1.23i` literals (of type `std::complex<double>`) to `1.23if` (`std::complex<float>`).

Alternatively, replace `1.23i` literals with `1.23*I` (`I` is defined in `complex.h`).

Comment: Also complex literals require `C++14` and OP needs to compile for C++98.

Comment: also `1i` is a `std::complex<double>` literal. `1if` is a `std::complex<float>`

Comment: @MarekR To me it looks like OP's saying this code breaks in C++11 and above, and works C++98.

Comment: I tried what you suggested above, but got the error below:error: conversion from 'complex<double>' to non-scalar type 'complex<float>' requested
 +7.22087082e-03-6.08503353e-03i, -6.96312077e-03+5.01652248e-04i, +3.76169547e-03+2.33955798e-03i

Comment: So I used std::complex<double> instead, and it seemed to have worked.  And yes, I got it to compile in C++98, but need to compile in atleast C++11 or higher.

Comment: @mwk088 I've updated the answer. Yep, you can do that, or change the literals from `1.23i` to `1.23if`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I believe this is the answer. I do need to go through my cpp code and associated header file to update with std::complex<double>

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried changing the literals from `1.23i` to `1.23if` and now got the following error `error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'double' and 'std::complex<float>'`

Comment: @mwk088 It means you need to cast the first operand to `float`. (Or if it's a literal, add `f` to it.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the help.  I decided to use `std::complex<double>` and `1.23i`

Answer (score 0):

C++14 introduced the [`""_i` complex literal for doubles](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i), which is why you are receiving this error.

The C++ standard [guarantees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) that `std::complex<float>` is layout-compatible with `_Complex float`.
However, your use of `i` means you have an `std::complex<double>[]`, which is not compatible with `_Complex float`.

If you use the `if` suffix instead of `i`, you can define your array as `std::complex<float>`, which is identical to `_Complex float`.